# Searching a string continuously for a separator?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I'm writing my first program, and I'm finding it runs slowly. It is used to convert one text format to another. In doing so, I often have to search for a certain string and then parse the text from there. This may look like:

```
const string separator = "Parameters Table";

 // Get to the first separator
var cuttedWords = backgroundWords.SkipWhile(x => x != separator).Skip(1);      

// Run as long as there is anything left to scan

while (cuttedWords.Any())
{
    // Take data from the last found separator until the next one, exclusively
    var variable = cuttedWords.TakeWhile(x => x != separator).ToArray();

    // Step through cuttedWords to update where the last found separator was
    cuttedWords = cuttedWords.Skip(variable.Length + 1);

    // Do what you want with the sub-array containing information


}
```

I want to know if there is a more efficient way to do the same thing (i.e. search for a string and do what I want with the sub-array between that string and the next identical string). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What about something more direct like:

```
var startIndex = backgroundWords.IndexOf(separator) + separator.Length;
var endIndex = backgroundWords.IndexOf(separator, startIndex);
var cuttedWords = backgroundWords.Substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```

and you could just keep cutting it like that. When you wanted to move forward you could just do this:

```
// note I added the endIndex + separator.Length variable here to say
// continue with the end of what I found before
startIndex = backgroundWords.IndexOf(separator, endIndex + separator.Length) + separator.Length;
endIndex = backgroundWords.IndexOf(separator, startIndex);
cuttedWords = backgroundWords.Substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```

So, you're modified code snippet would look like this:

```
const string separator = "Parameters Table";

var startIndex = backgroundWords.IndexOf(separator) + separator.Length;
var endIndex = backgroundWords.IndexOf(separator, startIndex);
var cuttedWords = backgroundWords.Substring(startIndex, endIndex);

while (cuttedWords.Any())
{
    // Take data from the last found separator until the next one, exclusively
    var variable = cuttedWords.TakeWhile(x => x != separator).ToArray();

    // Step through cuttedWords to update where the last found separator was
    cuttedWords = cuttedWords.Skip(variable.Length + 1);

    startIndex = backgroundWords.IndexOf(separator, endIndex + separator.Length) + separator.Length;
    endIndex = backgroundWords.IndexOf(separator, startIndex);
    cuttedWords = backgroundWords.Substring(startIndex, endIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to just split the string.

```
const string separator = "Parameters Table";
var text = "ThisParameters TableisParameters TableaParameters Tabletest";
var split = text.Split(new[] { separator }, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach(var x in split)
{
    // do something
}
```

Is there a reason that this won't work?

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a list before entering the loop. Otherwise the Linq inner work will be repeated each time.

You could try like this:

```
var lst = cuttedWords.ToList();
while (lst.count() > 0)
{
    // Take data from the last found separator until the next one, exclusively
    var variable = lst.TakeWhile(x => x != separator).ToArray();

    // Step through cuttedWords to update where the last found separator was
    lst = lst.Skip(variable.Length + 1).ToList();

    // Do what you want with the sub-array containing information


}
```